# How to parse list of strings to dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
['name = case1101',
 '',
 "version = '2';",
 '',
 'alpha = [',
 '\t1\t3\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t1.06\t0\t0\t1\t1.06\t0.94;',
 '\t2\t2\t21.7\t12.7\t0\t0\t1\t1.045\t-4.98\t0\t1\t1.06\t0.94;',
 '];',
 '',
 'beta = [',
 '\t1\t232.4\t-16.9\t10\t0\t1.06\t100\t1\t332.4\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0;',
 '\t2\t40\t42.4\t50\t-40\t1.045\t100\t1\t140\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0;',
 '];',
 '',
 'gamma = [',
 '\t1\t2\t0.01938\t0.05917\t0.0528\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t-360\t360;',
 '\t1\t5\t0.05403\t0.22304\t0.0492\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t-360\t360;',
 '\t2\t3\t0.04699\t0.19797\t0.0438\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t-360\t360;',
 '];',
 '']
```

Which I need to convert to something like the following:

```
case = {
    "name": "case1101",
    "version": "2",
    "alpha": np.arrray([[1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.06, 0.94]...])
}
```

i.e. I need to parse the list of strings into a dictionary, whereby alpha, beta and gamma and arrays of their floats.

Im not sure how to do this, any advice is appreciated!

I have tried:

```
lines = "\n".join(lines);
search = re.search("alpha = \[([-\s0-9e.;]+)\]", lines).group(1);
np.array([[float(v) for v in r.strip().split()] for r in s.strip(';\n\t ').split(';')]);
```

But wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow.com isn't a free coding site, it's a Q&A site...

Comment: @ShayNehmad I have updated post with my attempt

Comment: Did your attempt work?

Comment: It worked but Im asking if there is a more efficient way to do this, as my way is quite messy

Comment: Why do you have efficiency concerns? It worked, and it ran faster than you could blink, didn't it?

Comment: Have you made a complete solution using the code snippets in your post?

Comment: If you want your code reviewed, you should probably use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
import re

def to_numpy(v):
    ' Converts data in capture groups to numpy array'
    v = v[2:-1].replace(';', '')                          # Drop brackets [] and ;
    rows = v.count('\n')                                  # number of rows of data
    return np.fromstring(v, dtype = float, sep='\t').reshape(rows, -1)   # numpy with 'rows' of data
    
s = "\n".join(lines)             # converts list of strings to string
case = {}
for m in re.finditer(r"(?s)(\w+) = (\w+|'\d+'|\[.*?\])"):
    k, v = m.group(1), m.group(2)
    case[k] = to_numpy(v) if v[0] == '[' else v
```

**Explanation**

To find name value pairs in string we use re.finditer [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
re.finditer(r"(?s)(\w+) = (\w+|'\d+'|\[.*?\])")
```

- (?s) : Makes the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline
- (\w+) : used to match key.  \w+ matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore.
- =    - matches " = " between key and value fields
- (\w+|'\d+'|[.*?]) - matches either word, digits in quotes or any characters in brackets

**Output**

```
{'name': 'case1101',
 'version': "'2'",
 'alpha': array([[ 1.   ,  3.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.06 ,
          0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.06 ,  0.94 ],
        [ 2.   ,  2.   , 21.7  , 12.7  ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.045,
         -4.98 ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.06 ,  0.94 ]]),
 'beta': array([[  1.   , 232.4  , -16.9  ,  10.   ,   0.   ,   1.06 , 100.   ,
           1.   , 332.4  ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,
           0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ],
        [  2.   ,  40.   ,  42.4  ,  50.   , -40.   ,   1.045, 100.   ,
           1.   , 140.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,
           0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ]]),
 'gamma': array([[ 1.0000e+00,  2.0000e+00,  1.9380e-02,  5.9170e-02,  5.2800e-02,
          0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00, -3.6000e+02,  3.6000e+02],
        [ 1.0000e+00,  5.0000e+00,  5.4030e-02,  2.2304e-01,  4.9200e-02,
          0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00, -3.6000e+02,  3.6000e+02],
        [ 2.0000e+00,  3.0000e+00,  4.6990e-02,  1.9797e-01,  4.3800e-02,
          0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00, -3.6000e+02,  3.6000e+02]])}
```